# Plotting many (i.e. 1000+) distributions on one plot in R

Tags: r, statistics, visualization

I'm trying to plot 18000 distributions as a heatmap type thing in R
One row can easily be plotted as a histogram but as i need to represent so many the only option I can think of is a heatmap.
This is not currently working as all the heatmap/imaging functions seem to do some kind of clustering/compare the rows instead of just plotting the distribution like in a histogram.

Does anyone know how to get around the problem or a better way of representing a large number of distribution?

```
    matrix <- replicate(100, rnorm(100))
    hist(matrix[1,],breaks = 60)

    image2D(z=matrix, border="black")
```

image2D doesn't seem to do the trick...

Thanks

Edit 12/06/18:

Using

```
library(denstrip)
```

Does the trick for anyone who needs to visualise differences in a large amount of distributions.

Comment: "plot 18000 distributions" In general, you can't visualize that many distributions in a way that is useful to the reader by actually plotting them.

Comment: what package is `image2D` from? I don't think it's part of base R ...

Comment: not sure what you want to do, but `Rowv=NA, Colv=NA` will turn off the ordering/dendograms in `heatmap()`

Answer (score 0):

You could overlay a lot of density plots using transparancy to get a sense of overlap.

```
m <- replicate(100, rnorm(100))

plot(range(m), c(0, 0.5), type = 'n')
for (i in 1:ncol(m)) lines(density(m[, i]), col = rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
```